# Multiple Updates in Check Box of Data Grid View

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to update the status of Column based on the Checkbox Column 'Status'.
I am right not able to update only one row at a time. I need multiple updates to happen at the same time.

[image]

Below is my piece of code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        if (row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["txtStatus"].Value) == true)
            {
                con.Open();
                string query = @"update tbl_Training_Records_CIP_dotnet set Attendance_Status = 'Attended' where RequestId=@RequestId";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
               // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@training_id", row.Cells["txt_Training_ID"].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestId", row.Cells["txtRequestId"].Value.ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Records have been updated");
                con.Close();
                loaddatatable2();
            }
        }
```

Comment: why did you call loaddatatable2() function? it should be outside the foreach loop (also message box). I think this function loads the value in the data grid view so when the first update query happens it loads the data and it vanishes all the remaining values.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvPendingApprovals.Rows)
{

    int rid = int.Parse(dgvPendingApprovals[1, dr.Index].Value.ToString());
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ch1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
    ch1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dr.Cells[0];
    try
    {
        switch (ch1.Value.ToString())
        {
            case "False":
                ch1.Value = false;
                break;
            case "True":
                cmd.CommandText = "Update ApplicantDetails set Status2 = 'Yes', ApprovedDate2 =  getdate() where Id = '" + rid + "'";
                cmd.Connection = conobj.getConn();
                conobj.openCon();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conobj.closeCon();
                rid = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Horrible exception handling.

Comment: Doesn't Work Mangesh